# How to use database codeigniter class without codeIgniter MVC framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My goal is to use the CodeIgniter database Class, but inside a plain PHP script. 
I don't want to use MVC structure for this.

Can I use this database class **WITHOUT** using the CodeIgniter MVC pattern?

If yes, how?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: you can use php include to include the db class

Comment: How does this have 3 upvotes?

Comment: What part of the class do you want to use? Is it for database connections or using Active Record?

Comment: @Qix, why do you ask? What's wrong with the question?

Comment: I can't speak for @Qix on this but my take is that firstly, usually the best questions show that you have at least tried yourself and come to us with a more specific problem, in which case you can include some example of your code.  Secondly, there are so many standalone DBAL and ORM solutions out there that it seems a little like hard work to do what you ask, it's not something anyone here can reasonably expect to answer within 30mins or so.  If it takes more than that and isn't interesting to someone who is willing to answer the question then your chances of good answers is quite low.

Comment: To continue, I would probably mark this as too vague if I were reviewing this question in the triage queue. See this guide http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some helpful information.

Answer (score 7):

Please follow below steps to integrate Codeigniter DB Active Record

1. Download latest codeigniter from https://codeigniter.com/
2. Copy below files

   ```
   application/config/config.php
   application/config/database.php

   system/database/*

   system/core/Common.php
   system/core/Exceptions.php
   system/core/Log.php
   ```

   [image]

The directory structure is as above

3. Add database connection details in `application/config/database.php`
4. Create db connection(connector.php) file

   ```
   <?php
   defined('DS') OR define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
   defined('EXT') OR define('EXT', '.php');
   defined('ENVIRONMENT') OR define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

   $dir_path = dirname(__FILE__) . DS;
   defined('BASEPATH') OR define('BASEPATH', $dir_path . 'system' . DS);
   defined('APPPATH') OR define('APPPATH', $dir_path . 'application' . DS);

   function getDBConnector(){
       include_once(BASEPATH . "core/Common.php");
       include_once(BASEPATH . "core/Exceptions.php");
       require_once(BASEPATH . 'database/DB' . EXT);
       $conn = & DB();
       return $conn;
   }    

   $db = getDBConnector();

   print_r($db->get('users')->result_array());
   ```
5. Now include connector.php in your project and access DB object :)

Comment: geeting below ERROR:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_instance() in G:\wamp\www\CIDB\system\core\Lang.php on line 139